# Foreground Service is killed and Alarm not scheduled in modern XIAOMI, Huawei or Samsung devices

Tags: android, alarmmanager, foreground-service, xiaomi, huawei-developers

My problem? Like many guys here: **The system kill my foreground service and in other cases don't schedule my Alarm**. First of all I know that are a lot of questions of this topic here, but some of this have years and I want a most recent context. I know that many post said that I have to add my app to protected list, others said enable AutoStart but don't work. Maybe exist an actual mode to add apps to protected apps  list in those devices, I don't know. I read in dontkillmyapp but nothing works. Can anyone tell my if exist any ACTUAL SOLUTION for this issue?. Most be exist because some apps work perfectly, so, how do they do it?

Comment: Did you read http://www.dontkillmyapp.com? It specifically calls out for many of these manufacturers that there is nothing you can do as a developer.

Comment: Yes I read but don't work

Comment: Only I can do is show settings to the user and he changes the confirmation but even doing that don't work